# Returning custom property from flask-restless

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to return a custom property from flask restless such as

```
class Item(db.Model):
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
    owner = db.relationship("User",backref="items",primary_join="Item.owner_id==User.id")
    owner = db.relationship("User",backref="created_items",primary_join="Item.creator_id==User.id")        


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable = False)
    lastName = db.Column(db.Unicode(50), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(100), nullable = False)
```

I'd like to be able to return firstName + " " + lastName in the item for the creator in the 
/api/User/1 for flask-restless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do this without modifying flask-restless. If you look in the flask-restless source, in `views.py`, the method `_to_dict` explicitly iterates over properties of the object and only includes ones that are instances of SQLAlchemy's `ColumnProperty` type.

That function would be the place to start, change that code to include properties of some other type, and then add a property to your `User` class that concatenates `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: Update: Flask-Restless [added support](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/135) for [SQLAlchemy's hybrid_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), so now if you define your property with `@hybrid_property`, they should appear in your API. You must also define an `expression` on your hybrid property before it will work.

Comment: Since version [0.11.0](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#version-0-11-0) Flask-Restless' `create_api()` method supports a `include_methods` argument, where you can specify a list of methods defined on the model and whose return values should be included in the response. See [here](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#specifying-which-columns-are-provided-in-responses).